# How to override filter in android's ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, filter, android-arrayadapter

I have an ArrayAdapter wrapped around an ArrayList of custom objects.  I'd like to write a custom filter for that adapter so that when I call `getListAdapter().getFilter().filter("abc")` the list will get filtered by an arbitrary transformation of "abc".

I thought I would just try to override `ArrayAdapter.getFilter()`, but that requires I re-implement the private `ArrayAdapter.ArrayFilter` which requires access to a bunch of ArrayAdapter's private instances.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: I would also love to see an answer to this question.

Comment: I had the same problem. I ended up writing a blog post about this issue, and uploading an alternatative adapter implementation. I leave the link for future reference: http://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/filterable-adapter/

Answer (score 12):

First, take a look at the [source code of ArrayAdapter](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java).

You'll notice that it has private field `mFilter` that's only used in `getFilter()` method. So, just extend `ArrayAdapter` and override `getFilter()` to return your `Filter`.

It's best to implement your `Filter` the same way as `ArrayFilter`: as private inner class, so it has access to private fields of `ArrayAdapter`.

Let me know if this is enough info to complete the task.

Comment: Thinking through this, help me understand something. I have examined the source of the ArrayAdapter and inner ArrayFilter classes, and I notice that ArrayFilter directly manipulates the private member variables of ArrayAdapter. If I understand your solution correctly, would I not need to implement my own Adapter and Filter classes? This is the conclusion I came to on my own. I was hoping the bounty would lead to more creative solutions that involved less custom code. I didn't think this was possible, however, given that ArrayFilter is private.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Peter, but that is essentially the solution I was hoping to avoid.  As yock mentions, it requires copying or reimplementing large amounts of code.  I'd like to find a more elegant solution if possible

Comment: You only have to extend `ArrayAdapter` and override `getFilter()` - that's about 5 lines of code. Then you have to implement a `Filter`. Currently ArrayFilter is 60 lines of code. I don't know what kind of filtering you'd like to do but it is probably going to be of similar length. I can write this in under 30 min, yet this question is already open 3 days.

Comment: If you tell me what kind of filtering you'd like to do I'll write it for you, just for kicks.

Comment: You are right - ArrayFilter uses a lot of ArrayAdapter's private fields. Then you just need to copy the whole ArrayAdapter and change the code you need. Not 'elegant' but it would work. This is no more work than I anticipated.

Comment: Peter, I've awarded the bounty. Really though I was hoping to learn an alternative to copying the android class wholesale for what amounts to changing two method names in the performFiltering method. At the very least you've given me confidence in my own reading and understanding of the code, and that's certainly worth something. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I could give you a simpler solution as `ArrayAdapter` is pretty closed and does not allow access to it's internals.